# pdfMake how to have line on header only of a table like the way the attribute layout: headerLineOnly has it but using hLineWidth as a function

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I know I could use layout: 'headerLineOnly' in the table element but I need to have layout as an object.

I tried something like this but it wasn't delivering the results I needed. I just need the line to be directly underneath my headers and no borders elsewhere.

```
layout:  {
          paddingTop: this.setTopMarginOfCellForVerticalCentering ,
          fillColor: this.alternateRowColor,
          hLineWidth: function (i, node) {
            return (i === 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
          },
          vLineWidth: function (i, node) {
            return (i === 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve it with this

```
      layout:  {
          paddingTop: this.setTopMarginOfCellForVerticalCentering ,
          fillColor: this.alternateRowColor,
          hLineWidth: function (i, node) {
            console.log(i, node);
            return (i === 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
          },
          vLineWidth: function (i, node) {
            return 0;
          }
```